# Error with SPARQL query in SPARQLer

Tags: sparql, ontology

My problem is that I could query in SPARQLER (http://sparql.org/sparql.html), but now throws an error with my queries and do not know what happens.

I would appreciate if someone could help me.

I have the following query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX olm: <http://atenea.inf.udec.cl/~angelcastillo/OntoLexmath#>
SELECT ?individuo ?comuna
FROM <http://atenea.inf.udec.cl/~angelcastillo/OntoLexmathBasico.owl> 
WHERE {
?individuo rdf:type olm:Colegio.
?individuo olm:pertenece_a_comuna ?comuna
}
ORDER BY ASC (?comuna)
```

This is the error:

```
Error 400: Failed to load URL http://atenea.inf.udec.cl/~angelcastillo/OntoLexmathBasico.owl

Fuseki - version 1.1.2 (Build date: 2015-03-08T09:49:20+0000)
```

Really I do not know what happens.

Regards.

Comment: seems to me as if the endpoint just doesn't allow dereferencing external URIs... are you sure this worked before? (doesn't work with DBpedia either)

Comment: sparql.org does not load external files anymore.  This feature has proven too time consuming in maintaining the server.  You can download Fuseki and run locally.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 1 month ago if it worked. A pity :(

Comment: @AndyS. Having same problem as Angel. Did not know - until now - that SPARQLer no longer loads remote files. We need a SPARQL endpoint to expose federated SPARQL queries. The federated SPARQL queries process RDF and RDFa files. Is there an option, other than hosting a SPARQL endpoint, to process external RDF and RDFa files?

Comment: @AndyS your comment seems quite useful for people with similar problems - you should turn it into answer.

Comment: @JayGray The service has never been guaranteed so running your own server is more likely to give you the SLA you want. This is especially true of federated queries where every component has to be live to live.

Comment: Should now work (completely different issue).  Still no guarantees of reliable service or availability.

Comment: @AndyS. Thank you very much by the news. It works and I could do what I needed. I'm really happy, I hope SPARQLer operate for a while more.

Comment: @AndyS. TY. We use the pyRDFa extract for external RDFa files. SPARQLer is now processing those files as expected.

Comment: @jeen Good suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that the `sparql.org` query service is not guaranteed to be running.  Running your own server is more likely to give you the SLA you want.

The service is volunteer run.  Being open, it is subject to bizarre and erroneous requests and even with pragmatic defences, it is overwhelmed sometimes.

This is especially true for queries reading other sources (`FROM`) or making federated queries (`SERVICE`) will also need those sites to be running and correct.  These are outside the control of the `sparql.org`.